# Collaborative Filtering - Matrix factorization vs pearson correlation

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering, matrix-factorization, pearson-correlation

For recommendations engine what is the advantage and disadvantage of those technique (matrix factorization:ALS, pearson or cossin correlation) and how we deside which technique to use.

Comment: These two are not in the same category.  MF is a technique to fill in the matrix where the matrix is sparse.  Pearson is simply calculating the correlation.

Answer (score 3):

Collaborative filtering using a pearson correlation suffers from a few issues. I'll list a few of the big ones:

- Scalability
  When your database grows, it will take increasingly longer to calculate a pearson correlation between users. Since you have to calculate a correlation between each user, this will grow exponentially.
- Data sparsity
  This is a big problem for most recommendation engines. If you have a lot of user and a lot of items with a few reviews, it will become difficult to generate recommendations, since you have too little data to calculate a correlation between users.
- Cold start problem
  Technically, each method suffers from this problem, but matrix factorization handles this better than a collaborative filter. A cold start problem basically means that you have no or barely any data about a user. You can't solve this when you are using a collaborative filter. Period.
  You can use alternate techniques to surpass this problem, i.e. content-based filtering.

Determining which method you should use can be difficult. Matrix factorization outperforms traditional user-based and item-based collaborative filtering, but you have to decide if it would suit your model best.
If you don't have a sparse database, a collaborative filter would work well, but so would a matrix factorization method.

Here are some interesting websites containing data about these methods. In the end, it's up to you or your team to decide which method works best.

- Matrix Factorization Example: http://www.quuxlabs.com/blog/2010/09/matrix-factorization-a-simple-tutorial-and-implementation-in-python/
- Content and collaborative filtering: http://recommender-systems.org/

Feel free to ask more if this wasn't clear enough!

Comment: Matrix factorization is also a type of collaborative filter.

Comment: Pearson was never intended to be used for sparse matrix.

Comment: @user4189129 - can you apply pearson on the matrix from MF to get item-item correlation?